# React Native Compilando para IOS e APK

Tags: react, ios, react-native, apk

Olá Pessoal estou começando a estou começando a estudar React Native para um projeto e surgiu uma duvida.

Sei que tem a opção do Expo e sei que sem o Expo não tem como compilar para IOS no Windows mas eu consigo digamos exportar o código que fiz no Windows, para algum MAC e depois compilar para IOS? ou vou precisar escrever tudo novamente?

Grato

Comment: Consegue sim, tem uma pasta `/ios` no projeto. Você só não consegue fazer as coisas que precisam do Xcode ou outras coisas da própria Apple.